# Having trouble reading data from SQL database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, blob

I have a table named images in SQL with 3 columns, imageID, username and image. I am trying to get all of the pictures of a particular user into a single array but for some reason it is not working properly. I don't know what I am doing wrong. The images go into the listOfImages array and the name of the images go into the imageName array:

```
ArrayList<BufferedImage> listOfImages = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();
ArrayList<String> imageName = new ArrayList<String>();

try {
    myConn = connection

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE username=?";
    PreparedStatement statement = myConn.prepareStatement(sql);
    statement.setString(1, username);

    ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
    while (result.next()) {
            String getImageName = result.getString("imageID");
            Blob blob = result.getBlob("image");
            listOfImages.add(javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(blob.getBinaryStream()));
            imageName.add(getImageName);
        }

    myConn.close();
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println(imageName);
```

Error Messages:

```
Stack trace:Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
listOfImages.add( javax.imageio.ImageIO.read( blob.getBinaryStream() ) );
```

The issue is that I was incorrectly converting a blob to a buffered image. What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: And *how* is it not working?  Are you getting an error?  Are you getting unexpected behavior?  If so, what is your program supposed to do?  What is it actually doing?  etc.  Ideally, you should provide a [mcve], but at a minimum you need to describe your problem in detail.

Comment: I don't know what's not working from reading your question, but the If statement inside the while doesn't belong there.

Comment: it's telling me Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException. I tried tracing it but I'm not understanding where the source of the error is coming from

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include the stack trace.  Also, at some point it'll get to a line in your code, and you should also mentione which line is throwing the NPE.

Comment: listOfImages.add( javax.imageio.ImageIO.read( blob.getBinaryStream() ) );  i found it traces back to there. nevermind. but i thought this was the correct way to convert a blob to buffered image?

Comment: are you sure that the `image` column in the database is of type `BLOB`?

Comment: @ChrisWitteveen I have it as a longblob

Comment: @yuin265 can you see what the output is when you print `blob`?

Comment: It is printing out com.mysql.jdbc.Blob@22053a48 or some sort with different numbers after the @sign 11 times. I currently have 4 BLOBs in the database. The imageName array is also working correctly and printing out. This means that the source of my problem was the             listOfImages.add(javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(blob.getBinaryStream()));
line right? So I was incorrectly converting a blob to a bufferedimage?

Answer (score 0):

solved: I had null values for the blob entry inside the SQL database. When reading it the error was caused.